# Exporting coverage data from build machine

Tags: teamcity, code-coverage

I was working on team internal KPI's lately and I thought that code coverage/number of unit tests will be a great measure.

In our CI build pipeline we're using NUnit to run test and JetBrains dotCover to generate coverage report - everything works great and we have that fancy "statistics" page in Team City control panel:

[image: Team City Coverage report]

What I would like to do is to export this coverage data so I can generate HTML output for the current coverage status and keep it under control not necessarily in the Team City console?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any reports that teamcity shows, the convention is that it needs a **zip file** with an **index.html** page at the root. So for `coverage report` it would be `coverage.zip` and so on.

If you go the `workout directory` for your builds, you can find the `artefacts` that you want (coverage, test results etc) in the artefacts folder.